# How to print Seq<type> values to console using f#

Tags: types, f#, console, printf

i am try to print to the console, a sequence of types.  The type is defined as:

```
// (x,y,z,vx,vy,vz,m)
type Body = Body of double * double * double * double * double * double * double
```

How is this done? i ve started by defining the following function:

```
let pv ls = Seq.map (fun st -> printf "%f" st) ls
```

I am fairly new to F#, any advice i would be grateful for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to print the values of a sequence to the console, you can do it this way:

```
Seq.iter (printfn "%A") ls
```

You do not need to map the sequence to another sequence, just iterate over it and print each value.

I am however not exactly sure if this is what you asked for. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I am looking to print out each variable contained with the type, i.e.

Comment: double * double * double * double * double * double * double

Console: 
x,y,z,vx,vy,vz,m
x,y,z,vx,vy,vz,m
x,y,z,vx,vy,vz,m
x,y,z,vx,vy,vz,m
etc

Comment: Sorry, each type on a new line:  x,y,z,vx,vy,vz,m \n

Comment: Try the suggested code, it does almost exactly what you're asking for (the only difference is it prints the name of the type at the start of each line: Body (1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0).

Comment: You can get the exact formatting you're after with: Seq.iter (fun (Body(x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, m)) -> printfn "%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f" x y z vx vy vz m)

Answer (score 1):

Note that `Seq.map` takes a `seq<'a>` and applies a function to `'a` and returns a `seq<'b>`. You can look at `Seq.map` as the `Select` function in LINQ, which indeed returns a new list.

In your case, what you have is a type. It's not a list. So you can forget Iteration here for a second and consider the following:

```
type Body = Body of string * int * string;;
```

which gives you:

```
type Body = | Body of string * int * string
```

Then, populate that type like this:

```
let b = Body("string value1", 5, "string value2")
```

which gives you:

```
val b : Body = Body ("string value1", 5, "string value2")
```

Then finally, you can print it with the `printfn` function:

```
printfn "the body is %A" b
```

You are done!

Note that I used `%A` as a placeholder for the printing function, well `%A` is generic and it takes an object rather than `%s` that takes a string or `%d` that takes an integer

Answer (score 0):

`Seq.map` is only a projection. Look at the return type being the result of your mapping function. Whereas `Seq.iter` actually executes your function of type `'a -> unit`.

The `unit` return type suggests, that some side-effect is executed, in this case something is printed to the screen.

In contrast, your projection is only executed, when necessary, lazily on-demand.